# Minecraft Migration Cape Chances of Getting it

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Most of my friends have gotten the Minecraft migration cape and I'm still waiting on mine. I was wondering what are the chances to get picked in one of the batches and be able to migrate? I know this question requires some math to solve so that's exactly why I came here to ask it.

Answer (score -1):

You might need to 'activate' the cape in your setting on minecraft.net.

I myself needed to do this:

Log in using your Microsoft account on minecraft.net.

Go to profile then "SKIN".

Scroll down until you see "CHANGE YOUR CAPE - PC/MAC".

Then select the cape you want.

[image: cape]

If this doesn't work you'll just have to wait...

Comment: Sorry for downvoting, but I don't think this is what the question meant. You get the cape as soon as you are migrated. The question was about the chance of being able to migrate, not about the cape itself.